# Solr TermsComponent: Usage of wildcards

Tags: autocomplete, lucene, solr

I'm using Solr 1.4.1 and I'm willing to use TermsComponent for AutoComplete. The problem is, I can't get it to match strings with spaces in them. So to say,

`terms.fl=name&terms.lower=david&terms.prefix=david&terms.lower.incl=false&indent=true&wt=json`

matches all strings starting with "david" but if I change it to:

`terms.fl=name&terms.lower=david%20&terms.prefix=david%20&terms.lower.incl=false&indent=true&wt=json`

it doesn't match all strings starting with "david ". Is it meant to be that way? If so, are n-grams the way to go? And does anybody know if TermsComponent is implementing Tries or DAWGs or Raddix trees and if it's efficient?

Cheers,
Parsa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK TermsComponent provides **raw** (i.e. literal) access to the fields' terms, so if there isn't any term with space (normally there isn't, the whitespace tokenizer takes care of that) it won't match anything. TermsComponent doesn't implement tries or anything, it just enumerates terms in the field index.

IMHO ngrams are a more flexible solution for autocomplete.

The next release of Solr will have a [specific component to implement autosuggest](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-1316) (you could use it now if you use [nightly builds](https://hudson.apache.org/hudson/job/Solr-trunk/))