# Solr / SolrNet - Using wildcards for letter by letter search

Tags: sql-server, lucene, solr, solrnet

Hey Guys,
Im trying to implement some search functionality to an application were writing.

Solr 1.4.1 running on Tomcat7
JDBC connection to a MS SQLServer with the View im indexing
Solr has finished indexing and the index is working.

To search and communicate with Solr i have created a little test WCF service (to be implemented with our main service later).

The purpose is to implement a textfield in our main application. In this text field the users can start typing something like Paintbrush and gradually filter through the list of objects as more and more characters are input.

This is working just fine and dandy with Solr up to a certain point. Im using the Wildcard asterisk in the end of my query and as such im throwing a lot of requests like
p*
pa*
pain*
paint*

etc. at the server and its returning results just fine (quite impressively fast actually). The only problem is that once the user types the whole word the query is paintbrush* at which point solr returns 0 results.

So it seems that query+wildcard can only be query+something and not query+nothing

I managed to get this working under Lucene.Net but Solr isnt doing things the same way it seems.

Any advice you can give me on implementing such a feature?

there isn't much code to look at since im using SolrNet: http://pastebin.com/tXpe4YUe

I figure it has something to do with the Analyzer and Parser but im not yet that into Solr to know where to look :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stemming seems to be what caused the problem. I fixed it using a clone of text_ws instead of text for the type.
My changes to scema.xml : http://pastebin.com/xaJZDgY4

Stemming is disabled and lowercase indexing is enabled. As long as all queries are in lower case they should always give results (if there at all).

Issue seems to be that Analyzers dont work with Wildcards, so the logic that would make Johnny the result of Johni or Johnni is "broken" when using wildcards.

If your facing similiar problems and my solution here doesnt quite work you can add debugQuery=on to your query string and see a bit more about whats going on. That helped me narrow down the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't implement suggestions with prefix wildcard queries in Solr. There are other mechanisms better suited to do this. See:

- [Simple Solr schema problem for autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3773753/simple-solr-schema-problem-for-autocomplete)
- [Solr TermsComponent: Usage of wildcards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176747/solr-termscomponent-usage-of-wildcards)

Comment: Looks interresting but it doesnt seem to do quite what i was interrested in. Here is the schema im using: http://pastebin.com/fF5Kisgd what i want is the ID of those that partially or fully match something in "text" which i ask for. Text is a concat of all the fields of a given row in my database (using a view)

Comment: @mfriis: yes, that is exactly what I'm talking about. Can you elaborate on how your case is different?

Comment: Well it sounds like im on the right track anyway then. The output just seems plain weird: http://pastebin.com/H2M8aX2s im using this query: solr/terms?terms.fl=text&terms.regex=byg.*&terms.regex.flag=case_insensitive in my index i have multiple objects with "bygning" in its text field. Now what i need are all those objects listed with their ID and Type (the other 2 fields in my documents schema). The output here seems semi random (the names in the result list are known to me but partial at best)?

Comment: @mfriis: you might want to use ngrams instead.

Comment: I cant believe Solr cant do something that simple, there must be something i am missing. I find it hard to believe i am the first who needs to do a wildcard search where the full word + wildcard still gives a result of the full word.

Comment: @mfriis: not sure why you say that Solr can't do it, I pointed out several ways to solve this.